# Sum of reciprocal of cubes

Tags: calculus, summation

I want to find the sum of the following series:

$$ \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{ 2}{( 5k+3)^3}$$

I tried searching for  pre-defined functions (like the Riemann zeta function for instance) but I couldn't find anything to arrive at the sum of this series. Any help?

Comment: The series can be expressed in terms of the second derivative of the digamma function.

Comment: You can look [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) for that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The digamma function can be represented by the series

$$\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right)\tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ twice reveals

$$\psi''(z)=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+z}\right)^3 \tag2$$

Setting $z=3/5$ in $(2)$ we find that

$$\begin{align}
\psi''(3/5)&=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+3/5}\right)^3\\\\
&=-250\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{5k+3}\right)^3\tag3
\end{align}$$

whence we find the value of the series of interest is

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(5k+3)^3}=-\frac{\psi''(3/5)}{125}$$

Comment: Can we get the value of $\psi ''(\frac{3}{5})$ without using the assimptotic expansion?

Comment: I'm not sure as to the meaning of your question.  There are many different representations of the digamma function.  [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) are a few integral representations.  There are also different product representations and series representations from which one could differentiate and numerically evaluate at a specific value of its argument.